# PowerMod and Mersenne primes

Tags: programming, reference-request

Is the PowerMod function able to compute Mersenne numbers of large size digit numbers like M47 M48 found in this list http://www.mersenne.org/primes/
like PowerMod[a,M47,p]

If not, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: For version 10.4 or later, see [`MersennePrimeExponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MersennePrimeExponent.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon There are only first 44 `MersennePrimeExponent`s.